# cannot read property of undefined angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a very simple `service.ts` file. I can console log the `responeDataSent` object.

```
  CallFunction() {
    this.http
      .post<{ someObject: any }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/apicall1',
        InputData
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.responeDataSent = responseData;
        return this.responeDataSent;
      });
  }
```

In my `component.ts` file, how can I read this `response`. Please help.

```
  private context: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.context = this.service.CallFunction();
    console.log(this.context);  // comes undefined.

  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: remove the`subscribe` from `CallFunction()` and subscribe inside the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: The service method `CallFunction` should return the observable. You should then subscribe to it in the component method, and do the processing in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a better way to deal with this scenario is that your service function should return an Observable first:

```
CallFunction(): Observable<any> {
  this.http.post<{ someObject: any }>(
    'http://localhost:3000/apicall1',
    InputData
  );
}
```

Then in component.ts you can subscribe and the code can handle the response:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.CallFunction().subscribe(responseData => {
    console.log('response', responseData);
  });
}
```

Read further about Observables: [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Answer (score 1):

This is my way to handle `HttpClient` request. 
Return http post/get after call in function.

```
CallFunction(InputData) {
        return this.http
          .post<{ someObject: any }>(
            'http://localhost:3000/apicall1',
            InputData
          );
      }
```

And use subscribe after call function.

```
private context: any;
  ngOnInit() {
this.service.CallFunction().subscribe(responseData => {
      this.context =  = responseData;
      // handle your data here
      console.log(this.context);  // comes undefined.
 } 
}
```